# A ball rotating inside a rectangle, a QML project

Tags: animation, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a ball animating inside a Rectangle in a QML project as below and want that when it hits the borders of the Rectangle it returns back to the inside until it hits another border, then it backs again, an so on.

I've written this code for that, but don't know using what code make the ball return when it hits the borders!
Would you please help me?

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

 Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Ball_in_Room")

    Rectangle {
        id: root
        width: 700; height: 500
        border.width: 10
        border.color: "gray"
        color: "moccasin"
        property real xPos: root.width
        property real yPos: Math.random() * root.height

        Ball { id: ball }

        ParallelAnimation {
           id: anim
               NumberAnimation {
                        target: ball
                        properties: "x"
                        to: root.xPos
                        duration: 1000
                        easing.type: Easing.Linear
                    }
               NumberAnimation {
                        target: ball
                        properties: "y"
                        to: root.yPos
                        duration: 1000
                        easing.type: Easing.Linear
                    }
        }

         MouseArea {
             anchors.fill: ball
             onClicked: anim.start()
         }
       }
     }
```

**Ball.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.8

Rectangle {
    width: 20; height: 20
    x: 250; y: 250
    color: "blue"
    radius: width/2
}
```

Comment: What do you mean saying "returns back"? Do you want to implement a reflection effect here? I think this problem doesn't relate to QML. I't just calculation, you just have to implement some known algorithm to get right direction and collision detection. Btw, why don't you just get some 2D engine instead of implementing it by yourself? Take a look at [qml-box2d](https://github.com/qml-box2d/qml-box2d)  a Box2D QML plugin.

Comment: Thanks you. (+1). Yeah, I mean reflection. Consider you're in a room and using your foot shoot a ball. It goes towards the wall of the room then it reflects to back and hit the other wall of the room and it happens again until the ball stops. I mean how to make the ball feel the wall and gets back and so on. I want to solve this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple implementation of bouncing ball:

```js
Rectangle {
    id: container
    anchors.fill: parent
    border.color: "orange"
    border.width: 3

    Rectangle {
        id: ball
        property double xincrement: Math.random() + 0.5
        property double yincrement: Math.random() + 0.5
        width: 50
        height: width
        radius: width / 2
        color: "lightgreen"
        x: 300
        y: 300

        Timer {
            interval: 1
            repeat: true
            running: true
            onTriggered: {
                ball.x = ball.x + (ball.xincrement * 2.0);
                ball.y = ball.y + (ball.yincrement * 2.0);
                if(ball.x <= 0 || ball.x + ball.width >= container.width)
                    ball.xincrement *= (-1);
                if(ball.y <= 0 || ball.y + ball.height >= container.height)
                    ball.yincrement *= (-1);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I might have more questions for you and if possible please continue guiding me.

Comment: My question is about the last *if* in the *timer* body. When **ball.y <= 0**, it means that the ball is touching the top of the container, so we make the **ball.yincrement** negative by multiplying it by -1. That's decreasing the y coordinate of the ball. But why still the ball moves downwards ("increasing" the y coordinate) in this situation!?

Comment: As I said it is very simple implementation and probably ignores some specific cases. I still advice you to use some 2D engine if of course your target is not to invent it by yourself.

Comment: I need to complete this game this way. I don't know about 2D game engines but this simple game is like an exercise for me. If possible please tell me why when *ball.y* is zero, decreasing its y coordinate makes it move downwards!? It should make it move upwards logically.

Comment: I think I got it. :)

Comment: Ok, I guess you did. Anyway, you can check it using a debugger. For me this code working well, maybe your usecase is just different.

Comment: Hi, if possible please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853247/dealing-with-a-ball-rotating-in-a-room-and-restarting-a-timer-in-qml) example too.